# Wordpress How to change date format for _get_last_post_time function

Tags: php, wordpress, date, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using the `_get_last_post_time()` function to show the date of a last added post.

```php
_get_last_post_time( $timezone, array('date','modified'), $post_type);
```

So far this is all clear, but the output is in `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` format. How do I modify this in a different date format?

Source:

> https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8/src/wp-includes/post.php#L7076

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [From the `_get_last_post_time` <sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_get_last_post_time/)
> "This function’s access is marked private. This means it is not intended for use by plugin or theme developers, only in other core functions."

Use this function instead: [`get_lastpostdate` <sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_lastpostdate/)

`get_lastpostdate` will return a string. After that you could use `strtotime` function to convert it to time format. Then you could use `date` function to format its output any way you need to, for example:

```php
$last_date = get_lastpostdate();

echo date("M d Y H:i:s", strtotime($last_date));
```

The above format outputs something like this:

```
Jul 05 2021 16:30:13
```

Another example:

```
echo date("H:i:s", strtotime($last_date));
```

The above format outputs something like this:

```
16:30:13
```

Here is the documentation for formatting date and time in wordpress:

> [`Customizing the Time and Date Format in Wordpress` <sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://wordpress.org/support/article/formatting-date-and-time/)

Comment: Thank you, this works with `date("M d Y H:i:s", strtotime($last_date));`, but in this case I can also use `_get_last_post_time`, because it's a placement in functions.php, but I do get the point.